Bind symbol in user-defined function to environment internal to my function
I've tried to work my way through https://adv-r.hadley.nz/index.html, which seems like a great source, but I'm still stuck at the basics it seems.
I want to write a function "my_fun(boolex, probs)" which takes a user-defined expression "boolex" as input and evaluates it in an environment "e" internal to my_fun. I want to allow the user to write their own functions "user_fun" which should be able to call a function P(x) that is defined in "e", as it accesses arguments of my_fun that are not known to user_fun in advance.
Here's what I tried (this is a toy example, but the structure of what I want to achieve is there):

library(rlang)

my_fun <- function(boolex, probs){
  e <- env(caller_env(),
           .probs=probs,
           P=function(i){
             .probs[as.character(enexpr(i))]
           }
  )
  
  env_print(e)
  
  print(enexpr(boolex))
  
  eval(enexpr(boolex), e)
}



user_fun <- function(x, y){
  x>=P(y)
}


my_fun(
  user_fun(0.4, C), 
  c(A=0.1, B=0.2, C=0.3, D=0.4)
) 

However, I get the error that function P was not found. I'm guessing P in user_fun gets bound to P earlier, but even then I would expect it to be in caller_env() and available.
EDIT: I previously tried to set the closure environment of user_fun directly using something like
 fn_env(get(call_name(enexpr(boolex)))) <- current_env()

and specify P at the beginning of the body of my_fun(). This in itself does not seem to work, I guess the copy-on-modify semantics kick in somehow. But maybe something involving fn_env<- would be a more fruitful route?

Running boolex in a different environment won't also change the environment of the user_fun function.  To do that pass the user_fun and its arguments as two separate arguments, a function and a list of arguments, so that we can access user_fun directly enabling us to to change its environment to a new environment e with P. No packages are used.
my_fun <- function(fun, args, probs) {
  e <- new.env(parent = environment(fun))
  environment(fun) <- e
  e$P <- function(i) probs[i]
  do.call(fun, args)
}

user_fun <- function(x, y) x >= P(y)

my_fun(user_fun, list(0.4, "C"), c(A = 0.1, B = 0.2, C = 0.3, D = 0.4))
##    C 
## TRUE 

Added
In a comment it is stated that there can be several functions and presumably any of them could reference P.  In that case specify any such function in a separate argument, funs (a default is provided that assumes that the functions are defined in envir), and in my_fun create a proto object (which is an environment that automatically sets the environment of functions in it) containing all functions of interest.
library(proto)

my_fun <- function(expr, probs, funs, envir = parent.frame()) {
  s <- substitute(expr)
  if (missing(funs)) funs <- all.vars(s, functions = TRUE) |>
    mget(envir, mode = "function",  inherits = FALSE, ifnotfound = NA) |>
    Filter(f = is.function)

  .f <- function() {}
  body(.f) <- s
  funs$.f <- .f
  funs$P <- function(i) probs[[i]]
  funs$probs <- probs
  p <- as.proto(funs, parent = envir)
  p[[".f"]]()
}

user_fun <- user_fun2 <- function(x, y) x >= P(y)

my_fun(user_fun(0.3, "C") + user_fun2(0.4, "B"), 
  probs = c(A = 0.1, B = 0.2, C = 0.3, D = 0.4))
## [1] 2


Thanks. This is similar to something I tried before, setting the closure environment using fn_env(). This works for passing args separately, but I had a hard time getting it to work with an actual call. Unfortunately, I am trying to avoid splitting this up, since the actual function will take multiple function calls using ..., and is supposed to handle non-function expressions as well :-(

This is how I tried to achieve this: fn_env(get(call_name(enexpr(boolex)))) <- current_env()

See new Added section.

Such wizardry! Much appreciated!

When you define functions, they hold a reference to the environment where they are defined. This enables lexical scoping. So function look up variables first in the function body, then in the environment where they were defined, then the parents of that environment. They do not necessarily resolve variables in the calling environment. Since you define user_fun in the global environment, that's where it will look to resolve P() which does not exist. You can see where functions will resolve free variables using the environment() function
environment(user_fun)
<environment: R_GlobalEnv>

You can assign a different environment via environment<- but if that function uses free variables from the global scope as well, you will run into issues resolving both.
Here another example of what's going on
a <- 10
my_fun <- function(expr){
  e <- env(caller_env(),a=5)
  eval(enexpr(expr), e)
}

user_fun <- function() {
  print(paste("a", a))
  print(paste("caller a", caller_env()$a))
}

my_fun(
  user_fun()
)
# [1] "a 10"
# [1] "caller a 5"

You can see that the value of a inside the call to user_fun resolves to the global value of 10 thanks to lexical scoping. But if you explicitly go out of the default flow and reach into the calling environment you can grab the 5 value from the environment created when you ran my_fun.
You can read more about lexical scoping here: https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html?q=lexical#lexical-scoping
